# How to install Nemerle on Mono

Tags: mono, monodevelop, nemerle

I can't find the solution
**How to install Nemerle on Mono**

I've got Nemerle Studio , But I want to try mono with it.
Maybe I will make something for Linux later, now I want to try it on windows.

Comment: What do you want to get out of "installing" Nemerle on Mono? Mono runs regular .NET assemblies, so you should not need to do anything extra to run the Nemerle compiler or programs under Mono.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mono is able to compile Nemerle compiler.
You just need the latest Mono from master.
2.8.1 is a suitable version.

Answer (score 2):

I hear the latest builds don't work with Mono, due to some System.Reflection.Emit issues there.

Comment: So ... it must installs automatic or what ?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to get Nemerle binaries, they work fine on Mono, just don't compile.

Soon there will be official binary downloads on google code page.